# SQL to LINQ inner JOIN

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Could somebody help me form the below SQL query in Entity framework linq?

The AccountApplication-table has got two FK's:

> AccountApplication[AccountId]->Account[AccountId]

and

> AccountApplication [ApplicationId] -> Application[ApplicationId]

`select * from Invoice a inner join AccountApplication b
  on b.AccountId = 3 and b.ApplicationId = a.ApplicationId`

I do not have the AccountApplication entity table available in EF.

What I want is a list of invoice who belongs to the application(s) what the given account id has rights to. And the relation between accountid's applicationid's are in the AccountApplication-table.

[Screenshot of EF classes with navigation properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6cBJ.png)

Comment: *I do not have the AccountApplication entity table available in EF.* Why?

Comment: Why "I do not have the AccountApplication entity table available in EF." ? You can use Joins in LINQ for this.

Comment: EntityFramework automatically cretes some references object when you use FK's between tables. So on the invoice I have an direct reference to the Application-object from the Application-table. This is created automatically and the actual referencing table is skipped. uhm

Comment: Thanks Gert, Added an screen of the EF classes which also show navigation properties!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With navigation properties it's quite simple

```
var query = db.Invoices.Where(invoice => invoice.Application.Account
    .Any(account => account.AccountId == 3));
```

I hope you see now why they are called **navigation** properties. Inside the query you use them to "navigate" (access) the data needed, and the EF uses them as metadata for generating the necessary joins.

Comment: Thanks! This lead the way. In my case I had to do somehitng like this tho db.Invoice.Where(x => x.Application.Account.FirstOrDefault().AccountId == accountId)

Comment: Sorry, I've missed that. So it's `many-to-many` relationship and `Application.Account` is a collection. In such case, `FirstOrDefault()` is not good because it will pick a random account, you need to use `Any(..)` - I'll update the answer. Just a friendly advice - the next time you have similar issue, post the entity classes instead of a diagram.

Answer (score 0):

```
var records= (from a in context.Invoices join b in context.AccountApplication
              on a.accountId equals b.accountId
              where b.accountId==3
              select new {a.Id,b.Id,....etc});
```